# Best practices to avoid intermittent React Native/Android crashes in the render cycle (e.g. NullPointerException in UIImplementation.java)?

Tags: android, react-native

Users are seeing fatal crashes (generally a NullPointerException in UIImplementation.java:390) in various moments. They seem related to `react-native-navigation` transitions, but others have also reported them (issues #10755, #11524 at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/).

Other evidence is the existence of pull request #13994 and the following code in file `ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/ShadowNodeRegistry.java`:

```
public void addRootNode(ReactShadowNode node) {
  // TODO(6242243): This should be asserted... but UIManagerModule is
  // thread-unsafe and calls this on the wrong thread.
  //mThreadAsserter.assertNow();
  int tag = node.getReactTag();
  mTagsToCSSNodes.put(tag, node);
  mRootTags.put(tag, true);
}
```

Although it does look like a RN bug, it seems like it's a hot path and it's likely that something it's something in my code which is triggering the bug.

Are there practices which are likely to circumvent this issue, or antipatterns which usually lead to such errors (eg. failing to use immutability, etc)?